# disable screensaver

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, mojave, screensaver

I stop my computer from sleeping by going into System Preferences > Energy Saver > Power Adapter and sliding "Turn display off after:" to 'Never'.

[image]

But after a long time the mac screensaver turns on and I have to type my password to get back into the computer.

How do I stop that from happening?

I want my computer to forever stay as I left it, and not start screensavers or log me out or anything.

Comment: The only solution I have found is to use an app like Caffeine or Amphetamine to keep the machine awake "forever."

Answer (score 2):

From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences…, then click Desktop & Screen Saver. Click the Screen Saver tab. Then set **Start after:** to: **Never**

[image: Screen Saver Preferences]

If the option is grayed out:

> The system administrator has set the screensaver timeout. You can't change it without removing the profile, which will probably cause you to lose network access.

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5365810?answerId=23166521022#23166521022))

Answer (score 0):

Go to: System Preferences > Desktop/Screensaver then on the bottom left click "Start after....' and change it to 'Never'

[image]

Comment: What to do if the Start after button is greyed out and don't do anything on clicking.

Comment: That's a very good question. If there's not a simple explanation here, that might make a great stand alone question if you want to ask it @user318572

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the password requirement to quit the screensaver in System Preferences > Security > General.

Then your Mac will wake from sleep/screensaver with just a nudge of the mouse/touchpad, or a keypress.

Bear in mind that without this password protection, anyone can access your MacBook when it is unattended, or if they steal it.  The password requirement does not log you out: it just locks the screen.